# Create a file whose content is handled by a program

Tags: linux, character-special-files

I want to create a special file, of which the content will be generated upon reading from, and processed upon writing to. There should be a background process handling the file. A pipe is not preferred as it never allows dual-band (r/w simultaneously). Two named pipes seem good but they are two files not one. What I want is much like a character device file or those stuffs in `/sys`. How can I do so?

Comment: Those character device files are controlled by kernel modules, as are the files under `/sys`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps a unix domain socket?   This allows you to have only one pipelike file for both reading and writing, and it also allows multiple programs to read and write that file without interference.

Comment: @oskarskog while a good suggestion, note that the api's used to deal with UNIX domain sockets are not the same ones as those dealing with files, so it might not work

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only want to read and write streams (one character after each other), you can use a [pseudoterminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal). This basically works like a two-sided pipe where only one side ("slave") is visible in the filesystem (as `/dev/pts/X`), and the other side ("master") is visible to the program that created it. It has some additional stuff like line discipline and serial parameters on top, which you can just ignore.

There are two ways to create pseudo terminals, the more modern is to use `openpty` and then `select` on the master side. See `man openpty` for details. Google should turn up some example programs.

Comment: Problem: `ls` and `grep` generate colored output to this pty, that's not wanted. Also a shell running on the pty generates prompts (PS1) to its stderr.